# yum update MemoryError 1G memory free

Tags: mysql, memory, yum, openvz

I am trying to do `yum update` and getting "MemoryError". The server (OpenVZ box) has 2G RAM and Percona MySQL server running with 1G InnoDB buffer configured. The OS is CentOS 6.5, kernel 2.6.32-openvz-042stab088.4-amd64.

`free -m` output:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2048        728       1319          0          0         21
-/+ buffers/cache:        706       1341
Swap:         2048          0       2048
```

On the host machine, the box memory configuration is:

```
vzctl set 101 --physpages 0:2G --swappages 0:2G --kmemsize unlimited --privvmpages 2000M:2G --vmguarpages 2000M:2G --oomguarpages 2G --save
```

When I stop MySQL, `yum update` works fine. Why would MySQL make `yum update` fail if there is still more than 1G RAM free?

The full error output is:

```
yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.mel.bkb.net.au
 * contrib: mirror.mel.bkb.net.au
 * epel: mirror.overthewire.com.au
 * extras: mirror.mel.bkb.net.au
 * updates: mirror.optus.net
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in <module>
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 285, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 136, in main
    result, resultmsgs = base.doCommands()
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 434, in doCommands
    self._getTs(needTsRemove)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 99, in _getTs
    self._getTsInfo(remove_only)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 110, in _getTsInfo
    pkgSack = self.pkgSack
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 887, in <lambda>
    pkgSack = property(fget=lambda self: self._getSacks(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 683, in _getSacks
    self.plugins.run('exclude')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/plugins.py", line 184, in run
    func(conduitcls(self, self.base, conf, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/priorities.py", line 129, in exclude_hook
    repopkgs_archless = _pkglist_to_dict(conduit.getPackages(repo), repo.priority)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/plugins.py", line 592, in getPackages
    return self._base.pkgSack.returnPackages(arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/packageSack.py", line 499, in returnPackages
    ignore_case=ignore_case)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 1646, in returnPackages
    pkgobjlist = self._buildPkgObjList(repoid, patterns, ignore_case)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 1610, in _buildPkgObjList
    po = self._packageByKeyData(repo, x['pkgKey'], x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 754, in _packageByKeyData
    po = self.pc(repo, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 187, in __init__
    self._loadedfiles = False
MemoryError
```

Similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/297616/yum-memory-alloc-12-bytes-returned-null) but not helpful as I have way more RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I recommends you to enable vSwap memory model because it's simpler and more reliable than old UBC styled system. With it you can replace this `vzctl set 101 --physpages 0:2G --swappages 0:2G --kmemsize unlimited --privvmpages 2000M:2G --vmguarpages 2000M:2G --oomguarpages 2G --save` by `vzctl set 101 --physpages 2G --swappages 2G --save`

After this please show me this command result:
`cat /proc/user_beancounters`

This problems looks like memory problem but it related with secondary memory limits which can't show by free or top (only with cat /proc/user_beancounters).